# Prevent loss of element focus (Need cross-browser solution)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following solution to prevent loss of focus of the `#content` textarea when the user has clicked on a `.box` element:

```
// Detect latest element clicked
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    lastElClicked = $(e.target);
});

// Prevent loss of focus for textarea when clicking on tools
$("#content").on("blur", function(event) {
    if (lastElClicked.attr('class') == 'box'){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

In a few words, on mouse down save the target element that has been clicked. On the blur of the `#content` textarea check if that last element clicked was a `.box`. If it was then prevent default, refocus the `#content` textarea and return false.

My solution works perfect under Chrome but I still loose focus under Safari and Firefox. How can I make this work cross browser?

EDIT:

The problem with the solutions offered is that the element actually looses focus and is refocused after. In Chrome with the code above I never actually loose fucus, which means selected text stays selected.

Comment: try `$("#content").focus()` instead of `this.focus();`

Comment: `lastElClicked.attr('class') == 'box'` should be `lastElClicked.hasClass('class')` and `this.focus` should be `$(this).focus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

try this:

```
// Detect latest element clicked
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    window.lastElClicked = $(e.target);
});

// Prevent loss of focus for textarea when clicking on tools
$("#content").on("blur", function(event) {
    if (window.lastElClicked.attr('class') == 'box'){
        event.preventDefault();
        var that=this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(that).trigger('focus');
        },200);
        window.lastElClicked="";
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also this is a nice article on this bug which appears to be on Safari's part: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7768

Alternatively you could try this one:

```
$('.box').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).trigger('blur');
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
            $('#content').trigger('focus');
        },200);
});
```

finally I have to mention that it still loses the focus on the highlighted text which seems to me as an impossible task to achieve in this case!

Comment: This works on Firefox but I loose focus of any highlighted text, which I really need to avoid in this case. On Safari it doesn't work, still looses focus.

Comment: I found out that in Safari the `blur` event is triggered before the `mousedown` so you must check that it wont get disfunctioned and/or work on an unwanted element, check out the answer again, I think it should fix it!